# Angular and NodeJs app , throwing me error when get a url link SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: node.js, angular, get

Good develpers , in this app im makeing with Angular and Node , im having a little issue, because any time i try to fetch an endpoint already set in my back end it says

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (url...
```

Lets say i got this fetch to my back end Node like this

```
---FIRST--My constructor
constructor(private userService: UserService, private http: HttpClient) {}

---SECOND--On the ngOninit i evolve all the logic about fetching my end point
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http
      .get(`${baseUrl}/upload/users/${this.userService.userRenew.img}`, {
        headers: {
          'user-token': localStorage.getItem('token'),

        }
      })
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);=====At this point i ust pretend to bring whatever the data the response 
                                   grabs, but for any reason that error shows up setting clearly its
                                   issue when trying to parse the endpoint

       this.imgUrl = response;//variable which assumes the response brought by the fetch

        ........some code
      });
  }
```

[image]

Pretending to fix it i just established as response Type following the headers of type "text"....but also didnt work:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http
      .get(`${baseUrl}/upload/users/${this.userService.userRenew.img}`, {
        headers: {
          'user-token': localStorage.getItem('token'),

        },
        responseType: 'text',====setting a response type
      })
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);

        this.imgUrl = response;

         .......some code 
      });
  }
```

[image]

How could i improve this situation?...Thanks !!!

PD:referring to to the baseUrl, is a constant i declare containing part of the endpoint which is already set in my environment variables files
(const baseUrl = environment.base_url) and the userRenew is an object already created in the service which eventually brings as one of its items the img, which also would complement the endpoint :"${baseUrl}/upload/users/${this.userService.userRenew.img}"

Comment: Can you hit your endpoint in postman and check response, if getting valid JSON in response. If not then you cannot parse it.

Comment: the response to that end point is an image

Comment: what values are you sending as `this.userService.userRenew.img` and `baseUrl`?

Comment: sorry i just add a PD where in a explain that

Comment: simply the baseUrl is a constant that contains part of the endpoint to my back set in my environment, and the userRenew would be an object which already contains as one of its items the img string

Comment: From what I see, you are trying to convert a png image to Json, which is not possible and also doesn't make sense. are you trying to put the image in a Json file as string?